# Is p-value involved in Neyman-Pearson Testing procedure?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

It seems to me that, after having a predetermined level of significance, the Neyman-Pearson approach only requires to see if the observed $x$ lies in the rejection region or not. In this case, how can one relate it to the $p$-value? Or is it an alternative way to judge if $x$ is rejected or not by using $p$-values? After reading some references about Neyman-Pearson and Fisher's treatments, I am confused.

Comment: It may help you to read my answer here: [When to use Fisher and Neyman-Pearson framework?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23142//51823#51823) As for how the rejection region relates to p-values, the RR is defined as that region where $p<\alpha$.

Comment: It is an excellent explaniation. So under Neyman's setting, does it requre any property of T(x), so that p<α is equivalent to x belongs to the rejection region?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow your question, but there is no property of T(x) being in the rejection region except that p<a.

Comment: My question is that, how does p<alpha guarantee that x is rejected. Because Neyman-Pearson does not necessrily require p-value in the procedure, so I think this p-value has to be defined first.

Comment: Yes, p<a guarantees that x is rejected. The N-P approach is based on maintaining a maximum type I error rate, so alpha comes 1st, you figure out what T(x) is when p=a, & that defines the rejection region.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [pretty lengthy post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386369/p-value-fisherian-vs-contemporary-frequentist-definitions/632770#632770) with relevant citations about the Fisher-Neyman-Pearson NHST framework and its origins. As a reminder of some definitions which answer some of your questions (by making these two pieces more explicit):

- **The $p$-value is the probability of obtaining an estimate equal to or more extreme than the observed value if the null hypothesis is true.** Note that we can only tentatively reject the null, and can neither accept the null hypothesis $H_0$ nor can we accept the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ given this information.
- **The $\alpha$ value is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is actually true.** You may notice that this makes $\alpha$ and $p$ different things. The $\alpha$ value is a pre-determined cutoff or a "zone of danger" with which we approximate $p$ values potentially making wrong decisions. We can have $p =[.01,.02,.03,.04,.05]$ but the $\alpha$ here is always set at $.05$. We cannot ever know with certainty whether we have avoided a false rejection, but setting $\alpha$ low enough should, in theory, reduce the number of false rejections by a lot.

On to your actual questions, the Neyman-Pearson perspective was the first to adopt this very idea of $\alpha$ level cutoffs. While in their original paper which proposed this never discussed an explicit cutoff like $.05$, they present a very lengthy discussion of why this may be important (given the reasons noted above along with others). So unlike Fisher, N-P proposed a decision-making framework which explicitly built in $\alpha$ as a way to make hardline decisions about a given $p$-value observed in the data.