# alpha value in Bonferroni corrected test

Tags: r, bonferroni

I ran some analysis with Bonferroni corrected test in R. Now my supervisor asked me what the value for alpha is for my analysis and since I haven't changed the default value it should be same as default. The problem is that I couldn't find any documentation or code that shows me the default value for alpha.

```
pairwise.t.test(ctData.df$SR, ctData.df$cond, p.adj = "bonf")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**; `pairwise.t.test` doesn't set an alpha value, it gives adjusted p-values.

`pairwise.t.test` returns the adjusted p-values themselves, so it's up to you to decide on your own "alpha" (confidence level cutoff), if you're going to use the so-called [Neyman-Pearson approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23142/when-to-use-fisher-and-neyman-pearson-framework) to dichotomize results into "reject null hypothesis" vs. "fail to reject null hypothesis".  Adapting the example from `?pairwise.t.test`:

```
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month, labels = month.abb[5:9])
with(airquality,pairwise.t.test(Ozone,Month,p.adj="bonf"))

Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  Ozone and Month 

    May     Jun     Jul     Aug    
Jun 1.00000 -       -       -      
Jul 0.00029 0.10225 -       -      
Aug 0.00019 0.08312 1.00000 -      
Sep 1.00000 1.00000 0.00697 0.00485

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

So you need to look at the values in the table (which are the Bonferroni-adjusted p-values) and decide on the basis of your own alpha. For example, for the comparison of August and June (adjusted p-value = 0.08312), you could decide to reject the null hypothesis if your alpha=0.1, or fail to reject it if your alpha=0.05 ...

Unsolicited PS: unless you absolutely must, there's no reason to use Bonferroni instead of the default Holm correction. `?p.adjust` even says:

> There seems no reason to use the
>        unmodified Bonferroni correction because it is dominated by Holm's
>        method, which is also valid under arbitrary assumptions.

Comment: (+1). Just a side remark: the simple Bonferroni correction *has* advantages: not everyone manages to apply Holm's version correctly (e.g. a corrected p value below alpha is not necessarily "significant") and you can easily create confidence intervals corresponding to Bonferroni corrected p values.

Comment: interesting.  Can you expand/give a link explaining the first point? Do you know how one would correctly interpret the values that `p.adjust` gives when method="holm"?

Comment: It is just how Holm's correction works. So e.g. if the three p values before correction are 0.02, 0.022 and 0.04, then none of the comparisons are significant. The smallest p value is multiplied by 3 and thus not below 5%, so the procedure stops, even if 0.022 times 2 is smaller than 0.05 and 0.04 times 1 as well.