# Null hypothesis definition

Tags: hypothesis-testing, definition

why do we use H0: μ ≥ μ0 in a left tailed test and try to reject H0 rather than using H0: μ ≤ μ0 and trying to prove H0 is true?
thanks

Comment: You seem to have stumbled upon something like non-inferiority testing, but the reason is that we want to disprove $H_0$ in favor of some alternative. We are, in some sense, hoping for the alternative to be true.

Comment: Some people think absence of evidence (failing to reject $H_0$) is not evidence of absence.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion is helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23142/when-to-use-fisher-and-neyman-pearson-framework/51823#51823