# Chi-2 test: why do we set the alpha risk a priori, and not find it a posteriori?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

Let's test if `[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1]` follows a Poisson $P(\lambda=2)$ distribution (null hypothesis $H_0$) with a $\chi^2$-test.

The observed frequencies are `0: 6, 1: 18, 2: 17, 3: 12, 4: 12, 5+: 5`. Thus the observed value of $\chi^2$ is here: $C = \sum \frac{(n_k - N_k)^2}{N_k} = 7.1$.

### 1. Usual method

We fix $\alpha=5 \%$ risk (of rejecting $H_0$ whereas it is true) **a priori**.
By looking at a $\chi^2$ table with $6-1=5$ degrees of freedom, we find a threshold of $11.07$.
Our observed $C$ is less that this threshold, thus **we don't reject the null hypothesis**.

If we had taken $\alpha=30 \%$ risk **a priori**, the threshold would be $6.1 < C$, then **we would reject the null hypothesis**.

### 2. Other method (correct?)

We don't fix the $\alpha$ risk a priori. We compute the inverse $\chi^2_5$ for the observed value $C=7.1$, that is $78.7 \%$, or $21.3 \%$ if we take $1 - ...$.

Intuitively, we see that if $C$ (similar to a distance) had been smaller, e.g. $C=3.1$, then it would be higher than $21.3 \%$, here $68.5 \%$.

**Question: Can we conclude something about the confidence in hypothesis $H_0$ directly from the inverse function of $\chi^2_5$ applied to the calculated value $C$ ?**

How to formalize this?

Approach 2. seems to be close to the p-value approach (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNXso_riZag) around 16'57"), but not sure how to formalize it.

Note: I have already read many other questions about $\chi^2$ / Fisher / Neyman-Pearson such as [When to use Fisher and Neyman-Pearson framework?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23142/when-to-use-fisher-and-neyman-pearson-framework) but here in this context, what is wrong (or correct?) in approach 2?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fisher+neyman+pearson.

Comment: I already read similar questions @whuber, but in this context, what is wrong (or correct) in approach 2? (the linked question, rather philosophical, did not really help to understand this precise example).

Comment: That's precisely what this site search looks for: one method is the Fisher method and the other is the Neyman-Pearson method.  You can also search for threads discussing both hypothesis testing and confidence intervals: there is a close relationship between them and much has been written here on CV about that.

Comment: @whuber Yes, but what I've read about this is often theoretical in the linked questions, and doing it on a concrete example often helps a lot to understand the theory. In my example, what conclusion could we give with approach #2? I voted to reopen, because here, on a specific example, we can probably describe if approach #2 is totally nonsense or if we can conclude something ("accept H0" or only "don't reject H0"?)

Comment: How the question has been formulated might be confusing things a little, or perhaps is too vague ("conclude something" doesn't say much, does it?).  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are directly equivalent to the p-value of the test ($\alpha=p$).  Using this to assess the hypothesis might be controversial, but it's not "total nonsense"! You can find tens of thousands of examples of using p-values in such a fashion here on CV.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @whuber, I changed a bit the formulation, and I used more standard notations (I removed the reference to beta, etc.). I also try to express a clearer question in Approach #2. I see two reopen votes, maybe we can try? :)