# How to Simulate T-Values for Two Different Samples

Tags: r, t-test, sample-size, effect-size, cohens-d

#### Motivating Question

I had a discussion with somebody recently, who said that a 10 participant sample with a t-value of 2.1 is more impressive than the same t-value for a 100 participant sample. The argument made was essentially this: because the formula for Cohen's d includes $n$, by nature it increases the effect size for 10 participants, thus larger effects. This to me seems fairly inaccurate for a lot of reasons, namely due to the lack of reliability/power of the estimate along with the issue of generalizability, but by an extreme technicality it is "correct" based off this very specific criterion.

#### Simulating the Data

Setting that aside, I tried simulating two samples to answer this question for myself, one with 10 participants and one with 100. I tried setting the SD fairly high to emulate how high variation affects the distribution and thus effect size of the populations.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(effectsize)
library(ggpubr)

#### Set Seed ####
set.seed(123)

#### Simulate Small Sample ####
group <- rep(c("ctrl",
               "treat"),
             c(5,5))

response <- rnorm(n=10,
                  mean=50,
                  sd=35)

small.sample <- tibble(group,
                       response)

#### Simulate Larger Sample ####
large.group <- rep(c("ctrl",
                     "treat"),
                   c(50,50))

large.response <- rnorm(n=100,
                  mean=50,
                  sd=35)

large.sample <- tibble(large.group,
                       large.response)
large.sample

#### Cohens D ####
cohens_d(response,group)
cohens_d(large.response,
         large.group)

#### Plot Them ####
small.plot <- small.sample %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=group,
             y=response))+
  geom_violin(fill="lightblue",
              alpha = .5)+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x="Small Sample Groups",
       y="Small Sample Response",
       title = "Violin Plots of Small Sample")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Control",
                             "Treatment"))
small.plot

large.plot <- large.sample %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=large.group,
             y=large.response))+
  geom_violin(fill="lightblue",
              alpha = .5)+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x="Large Sample Groups",
       y="Large Sample Response",
       title = "Violin Plots of Large Sample")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Control",
                            "Treatment"))
large.plot

ggarrange(small.plot,
          large.plot)
```

#### Cohen Values

Looking at the Cohen's d values obtained, I get this for the small sample:

```
Cohen's d |        95% CI
-------------------------
0.24      | [-1.01, 1.47]
```

And this for the larger sample:

```
Cohen's d |        95% CI
-------------------------
0.05      | [-0.35, 0.44]
```

Immediately you can see that the effect size for the small sample is larger, but the confidence interval is also much wider.

#### Plotting Distribution

The violin plots also show why this happens:

[image]

Here the data is fairly evenly distributed in the large sample, whereas the small sample has some extreme values impacting the distribution, and thus likely impacting the effect sizes because of the differences in groups.

#### Unresolved

**My main question remaining is how to simulate the exact t value specified: 2.1.**  I assume there is a more direct way of simulating this, but I have no clue how that can be accomplished in R. I feel like there is some way by messing with the mean/SD in some respect but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Any advice would be great.

Comment: In order to run a simulation study, you want to use randomly-selected data many times.  In your case, you want to get rid of `set.seed()`, and then wrap your whole function in a `for()` loop.  You'll need a vector to save the results.  Maybe 10,000 iterations ?

Comment: That makes sense actually. But I'm still not entirely sure how to go about that, mainly because I am fairly inexperienced with for loops that are more complicated than the most basic examples.

Comment: I'll mock up a little example.

Comment: Thanks Sal. That would be helpful.

Comment: [Related?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/459510/247274)

Comment: Rereading the question, I'm not sure how the *t* value plays into the question relative to the *Cohen's d* .  But you could add the *t* value with e.g. `t.test(Response1, Response2)$statistic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is R code to explore the difference in Cohen's *d* for two samples of different size, both selected from the same population. (Here, normal with mean = `Mean`, sd = `SD`, and sample sizes, `SmallN` and `LargeN`.)

If I were going to conduct this study, I would probably randomize the sample size, and then plot *Cohen's d* vs. *Sample size*.  This would tell you if there is a sample size at which *Cohen's d* stays in a reasonable range.

```
if(!require(effectsize)){install.packages("effectsize")}
if(!require(FSA)){install.packages("FSA")}

library(effectsize)

N      = 1000
SmallN =  5
LargeN = 50
Mean   = 50
SD     = 35

SmallCD = rep(NA, N)
LargeCD = rep(NA, N)

###################

for(i in 1:N){

SmallResponse1 = rnorm(n=SmallN, mean=Mean, sd=SD)
SmallResponse2 = rnorm(n=SmallN, mean=Mean, sd=SD)
SmallCD[i] = cohens_d(SmallResponse1, SmallResponse2)$Cohens_d

LargeResponse1 = rnorm(n=LargeN, mean=Mean, sd=SD)
LargeResponse2 = rnorm(n=LargeN, mean=Mean, sd=SD)
LargeCD[i] = cohens_d(LargeResponse1, LargeResponse2)$Cohens_d

if(i%%(N/100)==0){cat(".")}

}

Data = data.frame(CohensD = c(SmallCD, LargeCD),
                  Group = factor(c(rep("Small", length(SmallCD)),
                            rep("Large", length(LargeCD)))))

plot(CohensD ~ Group, data=Data)

library(FSA)

Summarize(CohensD ~ Group, data=Data)
```

*###########################################*

***Addendum:***

Here's some code for my other idea, that plots *Cohen's d* vs. *sample size*.

```
if(!require(effectsize)){install.packages("effectsize")}

library(effectsize)

N      = 1000
MinN   =  4
MaxN   = 200
Mean   = 50
SD     = 35

CD = rep(NA, N)
SampleSize = rep(NA, N) 
###################

for(i in 1:N){
  
  ThisN = runif(1, min=MinN, max=MaxN)

  Response1     = rnorm(n=ThisN, mean=Mean, sd=SD)
  Response2     = rnorm(n=ThisN, mean=Mean, sd=SD)
  CD[i]         = cohens_d(Response1, Response2)$Cohens_d
  SampleSize[i] = ThisN
  
  if(i%%(N/100)==0){cat(".")}
  
}

plot(CD ~ SampleSize)
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Just a couple questions. First, what does the `if(i%%(N/100)==0){cat(".")}` part do as well as the `cat` functions after? Second, what does `runif` do in this situation?

Comment: *runif()* generates random values from a uniform distribution.  So, it's analogous to *rnorm()*.  ...  The *if()* ... *cat()* code will print a period to the screen as the code loops through, printing 100 periods  no matter the size of *N*.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. This essentially gets at my question, so I thank you Sal.