# Clarification on Danger of Inference on Predictors for Time Series Regression

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, model-selection

I am reading the excellent book "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" and in chapter 7, section 5 there is the small section.

> ### Beware of inference after selecting predictors
>
> We do not discuss statistical inference of the predictors in this book
> (e.g., looking at p
> -values associated with each predictor). **If you do wish to look at the statistical significance of the predictors, beware that any procedure**
> **involving selecting predictors first will invalidate the assumptions**
> **behind the p-values.** The procedures we recommend for selecting
> predictors are helpful when the model is used for forecasting; they
> are not helpful if you wish to study the effect of any predictor on
> the forecast variable.

Would someone give a bit more detail on the bolded sentence (emphasis mine) above? Why would applying a procedure to select predictors, like AIC or BIC, invalidate the assumptions behind p-values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely not specific to time series analysis (so I took the liberty of editing your tags). *Any* model selection procedure will try to select predictors that make the model "better". But the mathematical theorems used in calculating p-values - specifically, theorems about the distribution of certain statistics under the null hypothesis do not make allowance for this kind of selection. Essentially, the null hypothesis never included a selection step.

You can run a quick simulation of this effect yourself. Simulate $n$ observations data points, and a $n\times k$ matrix of predictors that are completely unrelated to the observations. Run a regression, and record the $p$ values of your coefficients' $t$ tests. Do this many times. [The $p$ values should be approximately uniformly distributed.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL1RqHrZQ8)

Now redo the experiment, but in each run do some model selection beforehand. Stepwise by significance or AIC, forward or backward, all subsets, whatever - it does not matter. Again record the $p$ values of the remaining predictors.

You will find that they are biased low, and badly so - but since your original predictors were completely unrelated to your simulated outcome, this should not happen. The distribution of the $p$ values is not uniform any more. So you cannot use low $p$ values to reject the null hypothesis any more. The model selection step invalidated the $p$ values. (And note that there is nothing about time series analysis anywhere.)

This is discussed at length at many places, e.g., [Is p-value essentially useless and dangerous to use?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134890/1352) (see also Gelman's pieces and the ASA statement on $p$ values cited there), or [How much do we know about p-hacking "in the wild"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/200745/1352)

Comment: That is very interesting and makes a lot of sense. And great example with the simulation. From what I gather from your post and others is that selecting predictors for a regression based upon p-value should be avoided and can lead to wrong conclusions. Yes?

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late, I had to take a little time off from CV. The key question is whether you want to perform inference (null hypothesis significance testing, p values). If so, model selection based on p values, AIC or other will invalidate all p values, which are predicated on estimating a single model, so you are right: model selection should not be done. However, if you *forecast*, you do not use the NHST machinery, and such a model selection step can (*can!*) be helpful.