# Causality of the regression

Tags: regression, causality

I have the same results for two regression

1) y= number of board directors in t+1 x= a dummy variable with 1 if there is at least an institutional investor among the shareholders in t.

2) y= a dummy variable with 1 if there is at least an institutional investor among the shareholders in t+1 X= number of board directors in t

The coefficient of the two regression are positive and significant.

I want to know which conclusion can I write regarding the causality of the relation.

Comment: You cannot say *anything* about causation. [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Answer (score 0):

[Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) is a statistics mantra. Regression does not tell you anything about causation. For a simple counter-example, imagine you used ice-creams sales to predict sunny weather and the model would work like a charm. Does this mean that eating ice-creams *causes* sunny weather? This is just a simple example and you could argue that the casual is the opposite, but for more examples you can check [tylervigen.com](http://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations), or do some random searches on [Google correlate](https://www.google.com/trends/correlate).

Check also the following threads to learn more:

- [Does causation imply correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/does-causation-imply-correlation)
- [Does no correlation imply no causality?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221936/does-no-correlation-imply-no-causality)
- [Under what conditions does correlation imply causation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534/under-what-conditions-does-correlation-imply-causation)
- [Statistics and causal inference?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/statistics-and-causal-inference)