# What do r (Pearson correlation coefficient) and R^2 stand for?

Tags: variance, r-squared, pearson-r, regression-coefficients

As far as I understood, R squared explains how much the variation in Y is explained by its linear association with X. And it's used as an indicator for goodness of fit of a linear model.

Then when should I use r (Pearson coefficient)? How is it useful?

Comment: Flagged this as a duplicate. I arbitrarily chose one possible question it duplicates but there are many. Have a look, OP. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29713/what-is-covariance-in-plain-language ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/does-causation-imply-correlation ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221936/does-no-correlation-imply-no-causality ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534/under-what-conditions-does-correlation-imply-causation ...

Comment: @gammer much appreciated!