# How many user interactions do I need to perform search relevance experiment?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, ranking, search-theory

I know similar questions have been asked many times here. But I still don't get simple formula or idea how estimate this.

I have site with traffic and I want to split portion of it to test new search relevance algorithms, i.e., result sorting. I will measure abandonment rate (searches without click/total amount of searches). I want to get this statistics with $\pm2\%$ accuracy with $95\%$ confidence.

Is there simple heuristic (something practical) I can apply to get required number of experiments ($10^3,~10^6,~\ldots$)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question relates to the idea of [statistical power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power).  There are a lot of threads on CV that provide information to help you think about this, search under: [power](/questions/tagged/power) and [power-analysis](/questions/tagged/power-analysis).  In particular, you may want to read through this answer of mine: [How to report general precision in estimating correlations within a context of justifying sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16985//30287#30287), which discusses the idea of *Accuracy in Parameter Estimation*--a framework similar to power, but specific to the question of how much data you need to get a confidence interval down to a certain size.